# How can you check if a local node is running properly?

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-node

I am running a Cardano node using docker, on the testnet, and now I need to check if it works properly and accepts `cardano-cli` arguments like querying and what not.

Is there a convenient way to do it?

Comment: What happens when you enter cardano-cli into the terminal of the docker container running the Cardano node?

Comment: Resolving it, as I reached success with connecting to the docker container and running the queries from there, and everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do that was to `docker exec` into the container, and `cardano-cli` works just fine from there.

Answer (score 2):

To run cardano-cli in the container:

`docker exec -it  -e CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH=/path/to/node.sock cardano-node cardano-cli`

So to check the tip:
`docker exec -it  -e CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH=/path/to/node.sock cardano-node cardano-cli query tip --mainnet`

I put cardano-cli as an alias:
`alias cardano-cli='docker exec -it  -e CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH=/path/to/node.sock cardano-node cardano-cli'`. That way you can just invoke the cli as if the cardano-cli was in your PATH.